# Adding arbitrary number of zeroes to a specific location of a buffer won't change the CRC

Tags: validation, math, crc

We just found what seems like a major flaw in the CRC algorithm and I can't find any article online mentioning it.

In short, when the crc result of the previous bytes is zero, every following bytes in the buffer with the value of zero will only trigger a "shift-bit" on the crc, which will remain zero and won't change.

We use the CRC16 CCITT algorithm with the start value 0xFFFF and the polynomial 0x8408 (equivalent code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252069/ccitt-crc-16-bit-start-value-0xffff)) but I think it apply to any CRC algorithm.

```
ex:
FF FF                 = 0xFFFF
FF FF 00              = 0xFFFF
FF FF 00 00 00        = 0xFFFF

FF FF BB              = 0xA7F4
FF FF 00 00 00 00 BB  = 0xA7F4
```

But, adding an additional zero anywhere else will change the result:

```
FF FF BB 00           = 0x3921
```

This is an easy sample, but it could occurs with any data buffer that the resulting crc of the previous byte give 0 (before doing the final reverse), the following zeros bytes won't be counted in the result value.

It just happened by luck that our application data packets always begin by FF FF 00, and that sometimes (after thousands of packets) the 00 was getting cut on the hardware level (RS-485 communication) which caused some major problems in our application, but the CRC was valid so we did not expect this to be possible.

- Is this a well known problem?
- Any easy solution to prevent this? I know we could add the buffer length and validate it, but I'm curious about what people usually do.

Comment: How about adding the buffer length to the CRC also? Probably a bit simpler than passing it separately. Also, on the firmware updater I maintain, we use both a CRC and a version number for comparison, which helps us deal with the collisions. Obviously your use case is different...

Comment: It is not clear what CRC you are actually referring to.  The CRC linked to uses the polynomial in the form `0x1021`, not `0x8408`.  The CRC you name, CRC-16 CCITT, uses `0x8408`, but initializes the register to zero.  The CRC you describe sounds like X-25, which uses `0x8408`, initializes to `0xffff` and exclusive-or's the result with `0xffff`.  That's three different CRCs.  So what are you actually using?

Comment: I'm not sure where he got the CRC 0xA7F4, but the byte sequences he provided can reproduce the problem with the [CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) implementation here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html). No matter how many zero bytes ar einserted, the CRC is always `0x16B0`. In fact, a sequence starting with `0x1D0F` causes the 0x1D0F CRC to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Dark Falcon (first comment): Adding the length to the CRC calculation won't fix the problem with the zeros. A version number wouldn't either. You would need to validate the length separately anyway.

Mark Adler: You can use any poly/starting number for calculating CRC, as long as both devices use the same. CCITT inverse starting with FFFF is actually quite common, google it. The problem is reproducing with anything.

Dark Falcon (second comment): Thanks, at least you see the problem. Would really like to know if this is a known behavior and see articles about it.

Comment: Oh and you get 0x16B0 because the site use the normal 0x1021 polynomial, not the reversed 0x8408 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).